# how to read text files on android builds for Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to read text files stored in the StreamingAsset folder on my Android phone when I build the game as an .apk file.

I know that for Android you have to use a different path to access the files by using

```
"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + fileName;
```

and store it into the WWW class. I have tried many ways but nothing seems to work for me as I am totally lost right now. My code looks like this:

```
void Awake(){
    string filePath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + fileName;
    // Reads our text file and stores it in the array

    string[][] Level = readFile (filePath);
}

// Reads our level text file and stores the information in a jagged array, then returns that array
string[][] readFile(string file){
    WWW loadFile = new WWW (file);
    while (!loadFile.isDone) {}
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(loadFile.text);
    string[] lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n");
    int rows = lines.Length;

    string[][] levelBase = new string[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)  {
        string[] stringsOfLine = Regex.Split(lines[i], " ");
        levelBase[i] = stringsOfLine;
    }
    return levelBase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streamreader for this:

```
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        lines.Add(line); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The line `string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(loadFile.text);` is wrong:

- `loadFile.text` already contains the contents of file you are trying to open with `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`
- Also you can't use the `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` method to access file from StreamingAssets on Android.